# Prefix icon overlapping content for select input-field Materialize

Tags: html, css, forms, icons, materialize

My team and I are currently working on a web app that needs a register form.
We decided to use the Materialize framework to ease the development of the front, and now we are facing something really unpleasant: the prefix icons for all our select fields are overlapping the fields.

We already tried to follow what we found on other websites - apparently, this is a known issue that may have been fixed.

So this is the code now:

```js
M.AutoInit();
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">keyboard</i>
          <input id="code" type="text" class="validate" v-model="sponsor">
          <label for="code">Code Mairie</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">mail</i>
          <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" v-model="email">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
          <input id="password" type="password" class="validate" v-model="password">
          <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" v-model="lastName">
          <label for="last_name">Nom</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" v-model="firstName">
          <label for="first_name">Prénom</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i>
          <input id="dob" type="text" class="datepicker">
          <label for="dob">Date de naissance</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_box</i>
          <select id="gender" v-model="gender">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choisir votre sexe</option>
            <option value="1">Homme</option>
            <option value="2">Femme</option>
            <option value="3">Autre</option>
          </select>
          <label for="gender">Sexe</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">favorite</i>
          <select id="maritalSituation" v-model="maritalSituation">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choisir votre situation</option>
            <option value="1">Célibataire</option>
            <option value="2">Concubinage</option>
            <option value="3">Marié(e)</option>
            <option value="4">Divorcé(e)</option>
            <option value="5">Veuf/Veuve</option>
          </select>
          <label for="maritalSituation">Situation maritale</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">work</i>
          <select id="professionalSituation" v-model="professionalSituation">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choisir votre situation</option>
            <option value="1">Retraité(e)</option>
            <option value="2">Employé(e)</option>
            <option value="3">Sans Emploi</option>
          </select>
          <label for="professionalSituation">Situation Professionelle</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">local_phone</i>
          <input id="phone1" type="text" class="validate" v-model="phone">
          <label for="phone1">Téléphone 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">location_on</i>
          <input id="street" type="text" class="validate" v-model="street">
          <label for="street">Rue</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s4">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">location_on</i>
          <input id="postCode" type="text" class="validate" v-model="postalCode">
          <label for="postCode">Code postal</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s8">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">location_city</i>
          <input id="city" type="text" class="validate" v-model="city">
          <label for="city">Ville</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn col s10 offset-s1" @click="register">S'inscrire</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run this, you will see that the result is just as expected.
But if you take a look at this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzQyN.png), this is the result that we have on our app.

I checked all the versions and updated everything, we are using:
 - `materialize-css`: `^1.0.0-rc2`
 - `material-design-icons`: `^3.0.1`

Any help figuring out why this happens would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we found the error was coming from a property added to a parent div (like 6 or 7 nodes above) that centered the text.
Still, it is strange that this error only happens for the `select` input fields, but the problem is now fixed.

Little tip to anyone experiencing the same issue: ensure that there is no property inherited from a parent node - even if it can be tedious - that results in a strange display.